# Should I separate ViewModel for Login and Registration in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 3 types of user in my application(in asp.net mvc-5): Admin, Doctor and User. In Models folder I've created 3 other folder, one for each type of user. Should I create a single ViewModel, suppose DoctorViewModel which will carry all information about doctor? Or should I create DoctorLoginViewModel and DoctorRegistractionViewModel and so on?

N.B: I have separate tables in database for credentials(email and pass) and for personal Information(age, dob, gender etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use one model User which will carry out all common properties with those 3 types.

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public UseType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum UserType
{
   User = 1,
   Doctor = 2,
   Admin = 3
}
```

And then if you want have separate views for each of the users, then you can create DoctorViewModel or UserViewModel as needed.

I would suggest you to read about [Role based auhtorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in asp.net mvc.

Comment: So I'll put the specific logics for each user in their dedicated folders and put the common properties in one place?

Comment: Yes, you should keep it as simple as it is. Use DotctorViewModel if you only have to render something specific for that page that differs from User or Admin. But if the 3 logics are the same, like (name, lastname, and etc.), you can use just one UserViewModel and pass it to view with additional UserType enum to identify the user type.

Comment: You shouldn't keep one Doctor class with Name property and one Username class with Name property it doesn't make sense. Use Doctor class only to add specific properties , then you just can inherit from User class and extend Doctor class if that's your case.